# Python3 (v3.2.2) extra bits when writing binary files

Tags: python, python-3.x, binaryfiles

I have been working on function to map the bytes of a binary file to another set of bytes. I am reading from and writing to the same file. My problem is that every time i do it i end up with extra bytes unless i move to the end of the file before closing it, here is my code:

```
with open(self._path,'r+b') as source:
    for lookAt in range(0,self._size[1]*self._size[2],1):
        source.seek(lookAt*self._size[0],0)
        readBuffer = array.array('B')
        readBuffer.fromfile(source, self._size[0])
        newLine = array.array('B',[mappingDict[mat] for mat in readBuffer])
        source.seek(lookAt*self._size[0],0)
        newLine.tofile(source)
        source.seek(0,2) # Magic line that solves stupid bug
source.close()
```

I am using the array module to read and write data since i got the same problem when i used read() and write(). I do not understand why the 'Magic line' solves the problem since that's never used. I will appreciate any insight i can get on this.

Comment: What is in the mapping dict? bytes or unicode / string? Also, what is in `_size` at `0`, `1`, and `2`?

Comment: Because you are using `with`, the last line `source.close()` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

#### Comment (answer follows):

I see the same behavior as you:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

filename = '/tmp/a'
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b'1234a67b8ca')
print(open(filename, 'rb').read())

bufsize = 3

table = bytes.maketrans(b'abcde', b'xyzzz') # mapping
with open(filename, 'r+b') as f:
    for i in range(0, os.path.getsize(filename), bufsize):
        f.seek(i, os.SEEK_SET)
        b = f.read(bufsize) # result shouldn't depend on it due to 1 -> 1
        if not b: 
            break
        f.seek(i, os.SEEK_SET)
        f.write(b.translate(table))
        f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END) # magic
print(open(filename, 'rb').read())
```

#### Output (with magic line or buffering=0 or f.flush() after f.write)

```
b'1234a67b8ca'
b'1234x67y8zx'
```

#### Output (without magic line)

```
b'1234a67b8ca'
b'1234a67b8zx1234x67y8'
```

#### Answer:

If your mapping is 1 -> 1 you could use `bytes.translate()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import io
import os
import sys

filename = '/tmp/a'
data = b'1234a67b8ca'*10000
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
assert data == open(filename, 'rb').read()
print(data[:10]+data[-10:])

bufsize = io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE

table = bytes.maketrans(b'abcde', b'xyzzz') # mapping
with open(filename, 'r+b') as f:
    while True:
        b = f.read(bufsize) # result shouldn't depend on bufsize due to 1 -> 1
        if not b: 
            break
        f.seek(-len(b), os.SEEK_CUR)
        f.write(b.translate(table))
        f.flush()

tr_data = data.translate(table)
assert tr_data  == open(filename, 'rb').read()
print(tr_data[:10]+tr_data[-10:])
```

It seems that [io.BufferedRandom](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/io.html#io.BufferedRandom) can't do [interlaced read/seek/write](http://bugs.python.org/issue12213) (bug in Python3) without `flush()`.

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question -- why? However, do you get the same result with my code?

Comment: (+1) for taking the trouble to reproduce rather than guessing at the cause.

Comment: @agf If your code uses interlaced read/write with `io.BufferedRandom()` ('r+b' with default parameters returns that) then the same bug applies.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time. That's pretty helpful, now i know i am not  going crazy. By the way another reason i am avoiding using bytes directly is that i remember reading that the b'14' string type is going to be removed in future versions of python and my code needs to work for literally forever. Thanks.

Comment: @user1013993: You might've confused it with `u''` syntax. It is removed in Python3 due to `""` strings are Unicode in Python3. Where did you read that?

Comment: It is very possible that i got confused, i am quite new to python3. I'll post it if i find it. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Having experimented with this a little, I conjecture that it is a bug in Python 3.

In support of my conjecture, I offer the following code (based on @J.F. Sebastian's):

```
import os
import sys

filename = '/tmp/a'
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(b'1234a67b8ca')
print(open(filename, 'rb').read())

bufsize = 3

with open(filename, 'r+b') as f:
    for i in range(0, os.path.getsize(filename), bufsize):
        f.seek(i, os.SEEK_SET)
        b = f.read(bufsize)
        f.seek(i, os.SEEK_SET)
        f.write(b)
#        f.seek(0, os.SEEK_END) # magic
print(open(filename, 'rb').read())
```

**When run using Python 2.7.1**, it works as you'd expect, and the magic line makes no difference.

**When run using Python 3.1.2**, it inexplicably requires the magic no-op `seek()` in order to make it work as expected.

At this point I'd suggest demonstrating the code to core Python 3 developers to get their opinion on whether this is indeed a bug.